# How can I change objWord Page Orientation from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm working on a project were I run a report and when the work is done I want Excel to select and copy a range then paste as picture in a new Word document.

As the size of the image is relatively big for a portrait orientation, I want Word to change it to Landscape mode. And that's my problem. Can someone help?

```
Sub PasteAsPicture()
    Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
    
    With Workbooks("Workbook Name").Sheets("Sheet Name")
        .Range("A1:S40").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    End With
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    With objWord
        .Visible = True
        .ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .Selection.Paste
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me - as is, the data fill a single Word page (if I change the code to wdOrientPortrait then the image is much smaller, filling only the first half of the page)

Comment: What exactly happens when you run your code?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad when I activate the created Word Application window, the image was pasted but orientation is Portrait....

Comment: Did you add a reference to the Word object library?  If not then you need to define a value for `wdOrientLandscape` - that's part of the Word VBA library and Excel VBA won't know what its value is without the reference.  If you use `Option Explicit` in every code module (and you really should!) it will warn you about undeclared variables.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks. Just replaced it with "1" and now works fine.

Just need to make Word change to narrow margin and my Sub is done.

Comment: Instead of '.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation' you should use 'objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation'. Likewise, you should avoid using .Selection for the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reference to the Word object library, the constant `wdOrientLandscape` will have no value in Excel VBA, so either:

- add the Word reference
- define the constant in your Excel VBA
- or substitute the numeric value (1 in this case).