# How can I make the word document orientation to be a landscape?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the VBA code I use. I tried to add `.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape` without a success.

```
Sub Export_EU_Quote()

Dim WdObj As Object

Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WdObj.Visible = True
Range("A1:E50").Select
Selection.Copy 'Your Copy Range
WdObj.Documents.Add

WdObj.Selection.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
    
WdObj.ActiveDocument.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set WdObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would like to export an excel page to word in landscape page format since the columns do not fit a portrait page

Comment: I do not see the Orientation line in your code anywhere?

Comment: See how `.PageSetup` starts with a period? That means it's referencing something from a `With` statement, but you dont have one, so of course it's not going to work. You need to qualify that object with (presumably) the word application object, in your case, that is `WdObj` - So, the actual line of code you should be trying is actually `WdObj.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape` - HOWEVER... If you havent included the reference to Word, then you will need to use its value instead, which is `1` - so... `WdObj.PageSetup.Orientation = 1` - and it matters where you put it.

Comment: I misspoke. `PageSetup` is part of the document, not the application, so try `WdObj.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = 1`

Comment: This answer looks helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104995/how-can-i-change-objword-page-orientation-from-excel-vba

Comment: Welcome Avichay Sabach! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change objWord Page Orientation from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104995/how-can-i-change-objword-page-orientation-from-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you so much braX!!!!
WdObj.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 solved the issue.